# Will it harm a fridge w R600a refrigerant to set unplugged through winter months?

Tags: refrigerator, samsung

I purchased a new Samsung Refrigerator. I learned it is charged with R600a and that the life span is not very long due to the inability to recharge the dangerous explosive gas.

I was hoping to expand the life of mine by unplugging it over the winter months when the lake house is not used. Will it harm or help or neither?

Comment: Will the fridge be inside at room temperature during the winter month or will it be exposed to the outside winter temperatures?

Comment: You need to make sure that if a child crawls into the fridge when it's empty that he/she can get out (or, provide a way to keep the child out, or prevent the door from closing).  You may want to remove the door.  Check your local municipal code to see what the rules are.

Answer (score 12):

R600a is iso-butane. It's flammable, yes, but hardly excessively dangerous. Billions of people carry some around in their pockets or have it lying around the house, as it's one of the most common fuels in lighters.

[image: Butane fuel]

*Image source https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.bonanzastatic.com%2Fafu%2Fimages%2Fec5b%2F2f20%2Fdf25_5296324495%2F__57.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=909cf9d6dff1fe523535af2e224fa1a6f97f95941095a2df0b5ce4322d450eac&ipo=images no endorsement implied*

[image: Butane lighters]

*Image source https://cdnimg.webstaurantstore.com/images/products/large/26462/118551.jpg no endorsement implied*

If handled with proper precautions (not mixing with oxygen/air) as any competent refrigeration tech should well be able to do, (they normally evacuate refrigerant vessels completely, and are trained not to vent CFC refrigerants to the atmosphere) it's not particularly dangerous. On the other hand, the odds that Samsung has made their refrigerator economically viable to service are approximately zero, regardless of refrigerant type. Those days are long past, for almost any manufacturer of a household refrigerator. Serviceability is almost entirely restricted to commercial refrigeration equipment at this point in time.

I doubt that turning it off for the winter will particularly extend its life, but it will save on the power bill (and **may be required** anyway if the "lake house" is not heated in the off-season - my R600a fridge specifies a minimum operating temperature of 55°F/12.8°C - attempting to compress refrigerant that has not evaporated is **definitely bad** for your compressor and will drastically shorten its life.) As others have already mentioned, keeping the doors open (and ideally cleaning up any meltwater from defrosting before leaving it) is vital to prevent mold problems.

Comment: Isobutane (R600a) is not the same as the butane (i.e. n-butane) which is used a lighter fuel. They are chemically different, such that R600a will have a higher vapor pressure at room temperature than butane lighter fuel, which may make a marginal difference in its flammability.

Comment: The difference is, indeed, marginal.

Comment: The amount of refrigerant needed for a domestic refrigerator is pretty small and self contained, so the risk is considered low. It's why R600a has found its way into your fridge but not your air conditioning unit.

Comment: @Crazymoomin However, in the event of a evaporator coil leak where the refrigerant flows into the well-sealed fridge compartment, there is enough oxygen to cause an explosion. That's why interior electricals, lights, fans and thermostats, are specially designed and sealed (potted) in R600a fridges. Leaving the door open to allow any leak to dissipate into the larger room volume is a good idea.

Comment: @user71659 Leaving the door open for an unplugged fridge is a good idea anyway to prevent mold growth and nasty smells and whatnot

Answer (score 8):

Unlike e.g. car A/C systems that generally always leak some refrigerant and inevitably need topping up, a domestic fridge or freezer has pretty much a sealed refrigerant path so they work their 20 or 40 years without any dealing with the refrigerant.

In short, don't expect shorter lifespan just because the fridge uses R600a.

R600a is not that much new so most technicians should have been already prepared for working with it, should a need arise. This will only get better when the warranty term expires.

Unplugging is good - as long as you leave the fridge dry, clean and with an open door (1cm or 1/2" gap is enough).

Be sure to keep the fridge door open when it is unplugged, at least for the first month or so. Otherwise you will get a bad smell inside. This is hard when the fridge is in an inhabitated room because people learn from early age that the fridge must be closed. You can tape some object at the door edge in order to prevent closing.

Comment: It may also be worth putting a desiccant in the fridge/freezer to be sure no moisture collects in there. It can be purchased from many home center type stores.

Comment: @Sean either the fridge open, or desiccant, not both. And one would need kilograms of it for an used fridge.

Answer (score 4):

Unplugging will reduce mechanical wear on the fridge. And keep it from burning energy when not in use. Those seem like good things.

See standard advice about how to prep a fridge that's going to be unused for a long time to avoid mold.

(What I've seen so far suggests you are overestimating the issues associated with R600a.)